# Can't login to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, environment-variables, gedit, environment

Suddenly i edit the `/etc/environmemt` variable.
after that when i restart my ubuntu then i can't login. when i enter my pasaword and hit enter then it back me to login page.
then i press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>  and login by the command. then when i am trying to edit the `/etc/environment` using `gedit /etc/environment` it show me **command gedit is available in /usr/bin/gedit**.

now what can i do for fix it?
Here is my screenshot
[image]

Comment: So run `sudo /usr/bin/nano /etc/environment` and fix what you did there.

Comment: Thanks. i fixed it